# What role is played by the "s'en" in s'envoler?

Tags: prépositions, verbes, verbes-pronominaux, préfixes

"Voler" means "to fly." And "en" means "in," while the s' is the reflexive.

Yet, "s'envoler" means to fly away, which is different from what I would expect, reading the above. (And google translate gives me "loin" for away, so I would expect that to appear somewhere in the expression.)

How does something like "s'envoler" or "fly in" become "fly away." Could this be a reference to something like "in flight?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Envoler* does not mean to fly into something, it means to go into a state of flying. This is a common meaning of the prefix [*en-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en-) (§A.2, B, C): *s'endormir* (to enter a state of sleeping, i.e. to fall asleep), *s'endeuiller* (to enter a state of mourning), *s'enrichir* (to enter a state of being rich(er), i.e. to become rich(er)), … Without the reflexive pronoun, the verb means to cause something to enter the corresponding state (*endormir*: to make someone sleep, *enrichir*: to make someone richer, …).

*S'envoler* is a pronominal verb. *Envoler* is never used without a pronoun. The etymological idea is presumably that the subject is taking flight under its own power, even if this does not have to be the case (“*Il ouvrit la fenêtre. Le vent fit s'envoler les papiers.*” = “He opened the window. The wind sent the papers flying.”)

Answer (score 1):

"Voler" means "to fly" and "s'envoler" means the "action that represents the start of the flight".

*L'avion s'envole* =  *l'avion décolle* = The plane takes off = the plane flies away.

And after than the plane has take off, *L'avion est en vol* = The plane is in flight.

So the "en" in "envol" is not the preposition in this case. And "envol" has not the same meaning as "en vol" in two words.